# How to translate UTF8 file into html-like notation

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, localization, translate

How to translate an Unicode file in French (any language) to a relevant file in html-special encoding. For example, the letter "e" with accent should be translated into `&eacute;` , etc...

```
é -> &eacute;
```

I need to prepare a localized file without UTF8 letters like "é", only it should contain the other formatting like `&eacute;`

Comment: You didn't specify language or platform, so give this a try: http://www.primitivetype.com/resources/htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php htmlentities see it on
[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 1):

The [*uniquote* utility](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniquote) will do this for you when you use the `--html` and `--verbose` options together.

```
$ echo niño difícil | uniquote --html --verbose
ni&ntilde;o dif&iacute;cil
```